# How to stop the reboot at kernel panic/crash

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

After a kernel panic, I can see the dmesg showing up and less than 1sec later, the system reboots.

- `/proc/sys/kernel/panic` is already at `0`
- /etc/sysctl.conf has already `kernel.panic = 0`

How can I stop the kernel to reboot when there is a crash? I would like to be able to read the messages for more than 1sec.

FYI: I'm using Centos 7.8 with `3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64`

The solution is here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4014411 but I can't read it.

Comment: Is your kernel compiled with `CONFIG_SYSCTL`? Post output of `zgrep CONFIG_SYSCTL /proc/config.gz`

Comment: that file doesn't exist but `/boot/config-3.10.0-1127.18.1.el7.x86_64` has `CONFIG_SYSCTL=y`